# RegEx Starts withs / Ends With

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to preg_match the "INCIDENT DETAILS" block and piecing different regex snippets isn't getting me anywhere. Thanks for any help.

```
>>ID Number: 0
>>
>>Employee Detail: 
>>
>>Vehicle: 0    , #
>>
>>Incident Details: Sample incident details. It may span any number of lines
>>and is always followed by a newline with '>>'
>>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
>>Praesent vitae dignissim diam. Phasellus a vestibulum enim. Morbi dictum
>>
>>Comments: ADDITIONAL COMMENTS HERE
>>
```

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Comment: `preg_match('#incident details#im', $string)` will definitely match "INCIDENT DETAILS" which you requested.

Comment: Try going through a regex tutorial ([example here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)) and learning what the different parts of the regex do, rather than combining bits of other regexs without understanding them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(Incident\s*Details.*?)(?=>>\n)
```

Try this.Use flags `g` and `s`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/nA6hN9/37

Answer (score 1):

One possible regex is:

```
/>>incident details:[\s\S]+?\n>>\n/i
```

This will match everything from ">>Incident Details" up to the next "blank" (save for the `>>`) line.

However I would probably prefer `explode`ing on newlines and scanning through them, building the blocks as I go. This would be a bit more complicated, but in theory more robust.

Answer (score 0):

Might work -

```
 # '~(?sm-)^Incident Details:\K(?:(?!>>(?:\r?\n|$)).)*~'

 (?xsm-)
 ^ Incident\ Details: \K 
 (?:
      (?!
           >>
           (?: \r? \n | $ )
      )
      . 
 )*
```